# rich:calendar does not display within ui:composition

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm new to JSF and I'm facing this weird issue. I'm sure it's a silly mistake but I just can't seem to figure it out. Basically, when I insert `rich:calendar` within `ui:composition` it does not display. My (simplified) template is defined like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title></title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:insert name="content"/>
        <ui:debug/>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

My index page

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ui:composition template="/indexLayout.xhtml">
            <h:outputScript library="javascript" name="common.js" target="head"/>
            <ui:define name="content">
                <h:form> 
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        From
                        <rich:calendar id="pickup" onchange="#{rich:component('return')}.setValue(#{rich:component('pickup')}.getValue())" 
                                       dayDisableFunction="disablementFunction" datePattern="MMM d, yyyy" value="#{reservation.pickUp}" />

                        To
                        <rich:calendar id="return" dayDisableFunction="disablementFunction" datePattern="MMM d, yyyy" />

                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <h:commandButton value="Redisplay" />
                </h:form>
            </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I define the index page without `ui:composition` it displays just fine. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place your `<h:outputScript />` **inside** the `<ui:define></ui:define>` since when you are using `<ui:composition />`, every `<ui:insert />` inside the template are replaced by respective `<ui:define />`. Everything outside `<ui:define />` is not rendered.

In your case the JavaScript function `disablementFunction` is not loaded so your `rich:calendar` doesn't work properly.

Here is how your index page should look like :

```
<ui:composition template="/indexLayout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:outputScript library="javascript" name="common.js" target="head"/>

        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                From

                <rich:calendar id="pickup" onchange="#{rich:component('return')}.setValue(#{rich:component('pickup')}.getValue())"  dayDisableFunction="disablementFunction" datePattern="MMM d, yyyy" value="#{reservation.pickUp}" />

                To

                <rich:calendar id="return" dayDisableFunction="disablementFunction" datePattern="MMM d, yyyy" />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:commandButton value="Redisplay" />
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**More info :**

- [JSF 2 templating with Facelets example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example/)